# Python: Issue inserting multiple records using executemany() into mysql

Tags: python, mysql

Im trying to post the json data into mysql thru pyhton like:

**UPDATE:**

```
@app.route('/gmradd', methods=['POST'])
def add():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        req_json = request.get_json(force=True)
        g.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO gmr (version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)',
        (req_json[0]['version'], req_json[0]['visitorId'],req_json[0]['dwellTime'],req_json[0]['poiId'],req_json[0]['srId'],req_json[0]['zoneId'],req_json[0]['poiProximityConfidence'],req_json[0]['zoneProximityConfidence'],req_json[0]['poiPresenceConfidence'],req_json[0]['zonePresenceConfidence'],req_json[0]['normalizedTime']))

        g.conn.commit()
        resp = Response('Updated', status=201, mimetype='application/json')
        return resp
    else:
        return """<html><body>
        Something went horribly wrong
        </body></html>"""
```

Im posting 2 records of json data in rest client app something like this:

```
[
{
"dwellTime": "0",
"normalizedTime": "1489574977000",
"poiId": "poi3",
"poiPresenceConfidence": "15",
"poiProximityConfidence": "1",
"srId": "sr3",
"version": "3",
"visitorId": "V123",
"zoneId": "Security",
"zonePresenceConfidence": "40",
"zoneProximityConfidence": "20"
},
{
"dwellTime": "0",
"normalizedTime": "1489574977000",
"poiId": "poi3",
"poiPresenceConfidence": "15",
"poiProximityConfidence": "1",
"srId": "sr3",
"version": "3",
"visitorId": "V123",
"zoneId": "Security",
"zonePresenceConfidence": "40",
"zoneProximityConfidence": "20"
},
]
```

Only the 1st value is getting saved!

Tried with executemany() and replaced %s with {0}','{1}',... like:

```
g.cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO gmr (version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}')",
                         (req_json[0]['version'], req_json[0]['visitorId'], req_json[0]['dwellTime'], req_json[0]['poiId'], req_json[0]['srId'], req_json[0]['zoneId'], req_json[0]['poiProximityConfidence'], req_json[0]['zoneProximityConfidence'], req_json[0]['poiPresenceConfidence'], req_json[0]['zonePresenceConfidence'], req_json[0]['normalizedTime']))
```

**Without using '{0}','{1} and if i use %s, %s,..**

I get: TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in **call**
>       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.handle_exception(e)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/py_gmr.py", line 56, in add
>       (req_json[0]['version'], req_json[0]['visitorId'], req_json[0]['dwellTime'], req_json[0]['poiId'], req_json[0]['srId'], req_json[0]['zoneId'], req_json[0]['poiProximityConfidence'], req_json[0]['zoneProximityConfidence'], req_json[0]['poiPresenceConfidence'], req_json[0]['zonePresenceConfidence'], req_json[0]['normalizedTime']))
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 281, in executemany
>       self._get_db().encoding)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 297, in _do_execute_many
>       v = values % escape(next(args), conn)
>   TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

**With '{0}','{1} :**

Trace back is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in **call**
>       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.handle_exception(e)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>    File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/py_gmr.py", line 56, in add
>       (req_json[0]['version'], req_json[0]['visitorId'], req_json[0]['dwellTime'], req_json[0]['poiId'], req_json[0]['srId'], req_json[0]['zoneId'], req_json[0]['poiProximityConfidence'], req_json[0]['zoneProximityConfidence'], req_json[0]['poiPresenceConfidence'], req_json[0]['zonePresenceConfidence'], req_json[0]['normalizedTime']))
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 283, in executemany
>       self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 283, in 
>       self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 240, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, str(m))
>
> File "/root/python-mysql/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 52, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorclass(errorvalue)
>   ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: You're using `req_json[0]['version']`, but `req_json['visitorID']` (notice the absence of the 0.)

Comment: What framework is this? Flask? Also, you should post the full traceback, not just a single line.

Comment: Both `req_json[0]['version']` and `req_json['visitorId']` can't work at the same time. One is for lists the other for dictionaries.

Comment: But you should use `req_json[0]['whatever']` consistently, which is the point that zondo and Klaus were making.

Comment: Ok now the record seems to be inserting, but in my json im posting at a time 2 records, but only 1 is inserting